# Allowing Users to Input text Onto an image

Tags: react-native

Has anyone ever implemented something like this in React Native? I was thinking of like a way to edit an image and add text to it like snapchat or instagram does.. but I can't think of how you would possibly start with react native in doing that

Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds pretty doable. Just gotta add some styling. To do that my render would look something like this:

```
    <Image source={require(url)} 
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: null, 
          right: 0, 
          left: 0}}
    >
    <TextInput 
       style={{
          position: 'absolute', 
          height: 20, 
          width 60, 
          fontSize: 24, 
          fontWeight: '600',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
          color: white}}
        />
    </Image>
```

To make it "editable" or something like that would just throw `TouchableOpacity` somewhere with an `onPress` that triggers a function that displays and hides the TextInput.

Comment: wow, you made that so simple haha I couldn't think of how to do it for the lift of me.. Thank you!